# Creating matrixes within simulations (in R)

Tags: r

I need some consultation in R. I seek to find a method that saves each calculation of "**rental**" within this simulation in a separate matrix.

**Part_of_my_simulation_is_described_below**

```
for(i in 1:n){

for(j in 1:antall.simuleringer){

**rental**<-rbinom(1,1,ikke.reforhan)

L1KS[j,i]<-if(L1kontrakt>=i){L1kontr.tot} else if.
```

Does anyone have some suggestions?

Comment: So save it in a matrix, i.e. define `rental` like you define `L1KS`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do sumulation like below, where I put the results of a simple reproducible sumulation in a list.

```
# seed for reproducibility
set.seed(1)

# define a list
my_list <- list()

# my sequence
my_seq <- 1:10

# sumulation block of code
for(i in my_seq){

  # matrices of random numbers
  # store matrices in a list
  my_list[[i]] <- matrix(round(rnorm(20), 2), nrow = 2)
  my_list
}

# a look at results
my_list[1:2]

[[1]]
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3] [,4]  [,5] [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10]
[1,] -0.63 -0.84  0.33 0.49  0.58 1.51 -0.62  1.12 -0.02  0.82
[2,]  0.18  1.60 -0.82 0.74 -0.31 0.39 -2.21 -0.04  0.94  0.59

[[2]]
     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10]
[1,] 0.92  0.07  0.62 -0.16 -0.48  1.36  0.39 -1.38 -0.39  1.10
[2,] 0.78 -1.99 -0.06 -1.47  0.42 -0.10 -0.05 -0.41 -0.06  0.76
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand fully given your example but, at least, the Bernoulli random variables don't need to be created recursively.

```
n <- 5
m <- 5
prob <- 0.5
df <- matrix(rbinom(n * m, 1, prob), nrow = n)
df
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    0    1    1
[2,]    1    1    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    1
[4,]    0    0    1    0    0
[5,]    1    1    0    0    1
```

I can't continue further as I'm not sure how the conditioning is made.